# Item being delayed from view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, calculated-column-formula

So I have a field in one of my SharePoint lists that shows a program status (shown below):

[image: Program Status]

This field is a drop down list but I want to set a rule that if this field changes to cancelled (which is a drop down choice) remove the item from the list but from the day it was changed delay it 7 days.

I know this is easy with a dated field and the formula would be [Today]-7 but with a drop down field I do not know if this is possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do that with a on change workflow.

You would configure it as:
If Program Status equals Cancelled
Add 7 days to Today stored as variable deleteDate
Pause until deleteDate
Delete current item

You might need to wrap it in impersonation or an app step if the user does not have the ability to delete items.

If you don't want to delete it but rather hide it, then instead of delete current item, you could update a new HideFromView column in your list to true. Then you'd modify your view in your image to show items only when HideFromView is equal to false.